# Impresión retrasada en R

Tags: r, ordenamiento

Estoy realizando un algoritmo evolutivo en R, tengo problemas con el ordenamiento de una matriz porque este no se realiza:

El ordenamiento lo realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
indices <- order(F)
P <<- P[indices,]
F <<- F[indices]
```

F es un vector de aptitud
P una matriz con el genoma

Cada renglon de P tiene un valor relacionado a F por lo que deseo ordenarlo  de menor a mayor pero el ordenamientono se realiza en la matriz  correctamente pero si en el vector.

Pienso que tambien pueden ser problemas en la impresion

Comment: Hola, primero que todo, para que a la gente le sea más fácil ayudarte puedes intentar obviar lenguage técnico de tu área como 'aptitud' y 'genoma'. También poner un ejemplo mínimo reproducible: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Si nos das un ejemplo podría intenrtar replicar y ver que sucede ;)

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

Además de dar mejor el detalle de tu problema y con un conjunto mínimo de datos con los que se pueda reproducir.

Puedes ir mirando varias cosas:

1. Hasta que sepas un poco más de "R" olvídate por ahora de la asignación "<<-". El uso que le estás dando no es el apropiado para este caso. Utiliza en su lugar la asignación "<-"
2. En tu caso, "F" son índices que contiene "P". Entonces a la hora de ordenar es tan sencillo como hacer:

   P <- P[ order(F), ]